# Let $f(z)=\exp(z)\cos(z)$ prove $f(z)=a$ has infinite solutions outside any circunference.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, winding-number

I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days but i can´t find a convincent solution. The problem says:

> Let $f(z)=\exp(z)\cos(z)$. Prove for all $a \in \mathbb{C}$ except maybe one only complex number $f(z)=a$ has infinite solutions outside any circunference.

The problem also ask for calculating that one complex number in case it exists.

The part of "outside any circunference" gives me a clue of trying to solve it by using the argument principle and the winding number theorem but im struggling to make clear conclussions on what they are helping me on.

I'm glad of receiving your help.

Comment: Does Picard ring a bell?

Comment: I have thought about it but i dont understand how to apply the Picard theorem when f is holomorph in all C

Comment: The "[Great Picard Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem)" says that in a deleted neighbourhood of an essential singularity, the function takes all complex values infinitely often with at most one exception.  This applies to the case of an essential singularity at $\infty$.  Do you know how to show that your $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$?

Comment: So as my f isnt polynomial then $\infty$ is an essential singularity of f(z) and takes on all possible values of C. Also as my f is entire, f(z)+a ,for any constant a different from 0, it has infinite zeros , right?
About the existence of "that one" complex number i am now thinking it does not exist because of the periodical cos, but i dont have it clear.

Comment: Since $f(z+2\pi) = e^{2\pi} f(z)$, if value $v$ was missing so would be $e^{2\pi} v$.  So that eliminates all possibilities except $0$.  But $0$ is certainly a value ...